# What is the easiest way to 'save as' in iWork?

Tags: iwork

The 'save as' option in iWork has changed when versions and Lion was introduced.

I often open up a doc make some changes - names, dates, prices - and then wish to save the doc in another location and under another name.

Currently I have to create a duplicate first and then save it with another name.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best practice would arguably be to *Duplicate* the document the moment you open it, then proceed with your edits. However, sometimes we open a document and start working, only to realize that it's now (in our mind) a "new" document based on the original.

Applications that support Lion's versioning will give you the option to *Duplicate and Revert*, meaning that they will make a copy of the current document in it's current state, then revert the original document back to its last saved state.

[image: image of Byword Duplicate and Revert]

If some unwanted changes have been saved within the original, you can use *Revert* to restore the original to the state you prefer.

[image: image of Byword Revert screen]

If a document hasn't been opened for a period of time, it will open in a locked state and you will be prompted to either *unlock* or *duplicate* it before you can make changes.

[image]

Comment: can restore to earlier version be quite reliable?  Sometimes I worry about the program being correct (on Windows), not to mention being able to go back and forth to different versions along the timeline

Comment: I've found the system to be reliable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **No**.

[Versions (autosave) is a feature introduced with Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/auto-save.html) and the logical continuation of making OS X more like iOS - in this special also more user-friendly.  If you want to save the same document using a different name, you *have* to create a duplicate.

Ultimately, you need to find a solution which makes saving as a duplicate faster:

e.g. You can assign a **shortcut** to Duplicate in
**System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts**.

This way it takes two fast steps to save the same document as a different name:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to create a duplicate.
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save duplicate using different name.

[image]

Comment: You could also define CMD+S to trigger 'Duplicate'. Then you'll have to redefine the shortcut for 'Save a Version..' and 'Save...' for new documents.

Answer (score 3):

Shawn Blanc suggests [A Hack to Get Back "Save As"](http://shawnblanc.net/2011/11/save-as-hack/) using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

> With a keyboard shortcut of Command+Shift+S, the macro will select “Duplicate” from the File menu, choose “Duplicate and Revert” for the original document, close the original document, and then open up a Save dialog box for the new document.

Answer (score 3):

Without third party software, the answer is

## Yes, you can.

The caveat is that you'll either need to repeat this for each of your iWork apps, or make it system-wide. I'm presenting the answer for Pages; repeating for Numbers and Keynote is left as an exercise for the reader.

Create a new **service** in **Automator**. The service takes **no input** in **Pages.app**.The service has a single action: **Do AppleScript**. The script is:

```
tell application "Pages"
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "S" using {command down, option down}
    keystroke "S" using {command down}
  end tell
end tell
```

[image: image of Automator workflow]

Save the service as "Pages Save As." Use the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab within the **Keyboard** pane of **System Preferences** to bind the service to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: image of Keyboard Shortcuts pref pane]

Answer (score 1):

Go into the File menu and hold <kbd>⌥</kbd>. "Duplicate" should turn into "Save as"

Comment: @Graeme This is THE answer!