# Is there a hack for "Save As..." command?

Tags: macos, numbers, pages, menu-bar, keynote

The only thing I like about Microsoft's implementation of the Common User Architecture is the **Save As...** feature, which makes it easy to use cloud storage, local backups, etc. I know, I know, you can always use "Duplicate" and "Move" the copy. That takes considerably longer than "Save As...". It's a real workflow-disrupter.

In recent version of macOS, this functionality has likely disappeared. Is there an easy way to get it back (or to add it to the menu again)?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44660/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-save-as-in-iwork

Answer (score 25):

With the File menu open, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key to get the **Save As...** command.

[image: Video demonstration of Save As...]

---

**Update**: Some new users of macOS may be concerned about the discoverability of the command, as it is not visible by default in the Pages menu bar. And most users aren't aware that the <kbd>Option</kbd> modifier key can alter the behavior of commands.

An alternate discovery approach that new users can take to discover a command is to go to the Help menu and search for the desired command. A match, if available, would be highlighted, along with its keyboard shortcut, even if it is not directly available in the app menu. The same is illustrated below for **Save As...** command in Pages for macOS.

[image]

The trick works in any native macOS app.

Comment: As discoverable as one can get...

Comment: @Ruslan Updated. I hope you find that slightly more helpful.

Comment: Oh, that looks much better. Is this white arrow part of the actual GUI, not what you've added yourself? I don't see the hint to press `Option` key to access the actual menu item though...

Comment: @Ruslan Native macOS GUI.

Answer (score 10):

As others have said, you can get ‘Save As’ with the Option key.

However, I prefer another way, which [I have been promoting since Mountain Lion came out in 2012](https://www.engadget.com/2012-07-29-get-save-as-back-on-mountain-lions-file-menu-easily-and-without.html).

1. Go to System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » App Shortcuts.
2. Click the `+` button.

[image: System Preferences]
Then enter ‘Save As…’ as the menu item and ⌘ ⇧ S as the keyboard shortcut:

[image: Second Screenshot]

Once you click ‘Add’ you will have the original keyboard shortcut for ‘Save As…’ back, since there is *still* no reason on earth why it should mean ‘Duplicate’. That was a dumb decision that Apple has stuck with for 8+ years.

Comment: Is that a custom theme you installed to give you green buttons instead of aqua? Or is the ability to change that color finally built in to some version of the OS?

Comment: @CodyGray System Preferences > General > Accent colour. Since Mojave there a more options than blue and graphite.

Comment: Mojave has had accent color options (and dark mode!) ever since its release, which was over a year ago.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the current document in Pages, Numbers and Keynote to a new location with <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>. Holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> when the File menu is revealed will display **Save As...** in the place of **Duplicate**.

Comment: This is a big help, guys. I am now contemplating if my AppleScript skills are sufficient to make the Save As when the option key flickers to the default menu.

Comment: No AppleScript skills are necessary! Just remap the keyboard shortcut.